# Is there a manual or automatic way to obtain prediction intervals from a model trained in H2O AutoML?

Tags: prediction, h2o, confidence-interval, standard-deviation, automl

I've trained a continuous variable using H2O AutoML, and selected the best model to predict on a new dataset. Besides the point estimation, I would like to obtain a prediction interval. In H2O documentation, there is no option to include prediction interval in AutoML. I was wondering if there is an additional package or a manual approach I can follow to construct the prediction interval of the best model in the leaderboard.

Comment: I opened a ticket [here](https://h2oai.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-8068) to add support in H2O, but I am also curious if someone can provide code to do this manually.